# How to plasterboard a garage ceiling

Tags: drywall, ceiling

Can I have a little advice please?

The joists run length ways, so naturally, I board across the joists.

However, the joists finish about 300mm from each side of the garage.

How should I support the board?  Add a batten all around the edge?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a photo? I assume you're stating that edge without support is the edge parallel to the joists...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add a batten to support any free edges.

Then plan the panel layout to maximize the use of panels ie have the fewest joints possible and the shortest total length of joints.

Comment: Thanks. Annoyingly, the length of the room will be about 2500 ish, so hopefully, not too much waste.

Comment: you can order sheets in any length (up-to the length of the delivery truck). sometimes that's preferable to accepting the retail offerings.

Comment: @Jasen that seems location specific info - 8 by 4 sheets is why the most popular van was the transit for many years...